# What i'm doing worng in this conditional?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Yesterday I asked a question about a script I was doing, since I could not detect the cell I was modifying, I leave in link to the question:

[Stuck with Google spreadsheet script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53702670/stuck-with-google-spreadsheet-script?noredirect=1#comment94266868_53702670)

Now I am trying to make the script conditional, but I can not distinguish between watchRange1 and watchRange2, these are two different cell ranges, which have a specific cell in which I want to write the time in which each range was modified.

Right now the conditional always writes me the modification time in the cell of the watchRange1 even if I modify the other range.

Can you tell me what i'm doing wrog?

This is the script that i'm mentioning:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+01:00", "hh:mm");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Test2');
  var range = e.range;
  //var colIndex = range.getColumn();
  var colIndex = range.getColumnIndex(); //Same as getColumn()
  var rowIndex = range.getRowIndex(); //Same as getRow()
  var DateCol1 = "K9"; //Cell you want to have the date
  var DateCol2 = "U9"; //Cell you want to have the date

  var watchRange1 = { 
    top : 11,         // start row
    bottom : 109,     // end row
    left : 3,        // start col
    right : 11,        // end col
  };

  var watchRange2 = { 
    top : 11,         // start row
    bottom : 109,     // end row
    left : 13,        // start col
    right : 21,        // end col
  };

  if(colIndex >= watchRange1.left || colIndex <= watchRange1.right && 
  rowIndex >= watchRange1.top || rowIndex <= watchRange1.bottom && 
  e.getValue() != 0){

    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(DateCol1).setValue(curDate); 
    //Write the date in the cell

  }else if (colIndex >= watchRange2.left || colIndex <= watchRange2.right && 
  rowIndex >= watchRange2.top || rowIndex <= watchRange2.bottom && 
  e.getValue() != 0){

    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(DateCol2).setValue(curDate); 
    //Write the date in the cell

  }else{

    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(DateCol1).setValue("Error");

  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using 'or' `||` instead of 'and' `&&`.
**Col** is greater than or equal to **left** OR less than or equal to **right**. **Col** will always be greater than **left** in the first range. This means the first `if` statement is always true (if you're editing in either of the ranges).

```
if(colIndex >= watchRange1.left || //should be &&

colIndex <= watchRange1.rigth && //right is misspelled
rowIndex >= watchRange1.top || //should be &&
rowIndex <= watchRange1.bottom && 
e.value != 0) //access key value instead of call function
```

Also, event objects `e` do not have associated functions. They have key:value pairs. `e.value` is how you access the value.

Comment: I tried to use && like you said, but it jumps me to the Error value.

Comment: Yes, i corrected that.

I had already tried before you told me

Comment: Try e.value instead of e.getValue(). https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Comment: The log give me this error:  TypeError: The Value function can not be found in the object   Same error with e.getValue().

Comment: You are using e.value not e.value() yes? There should be no parentheses.

Comment: My failure, is working know with e.value, i just missed to delte the ().

Comment: Thanks for the help @c0de

Comment: Now i should think a way for not repeat DateCol*, WatchRange*, and if. Cause you may have 20 direfent ranges xd

Comment: If you like, you can set the background colours of the cells to #000000 (white) #000001 (still white, but slightly off) then check the background colour of the cell in the script and assign a dateCol for each colour.

Comment: I dont want to bother you, but can you look this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53723435/dont-know-how-to-make-my-script-work-in-just-one-sheet     i cant make it work in just one sheet